# Is this good to store whole dataTable in Viewstate by Security and Performance perception

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

As by the Question .***Is this a Good Practice to store a datable  in view state***  If not then what i need to do for Performance and security measures.
What i lacks when i go with security and to performance and viceversa.

What i trying to do. is showing data in Gridview by DataTable(Source ) .In the postBacks. i want to save my Query Cost.Load data from view state or Cache object but not  by Database.

Comment: I would re-visit the answers below. The use of a DataTable in the VS depends on needs/requirements (and I use them a good bit for *temporal per-user/page data modifications*). It is not inherently bad, although *do* watch out for VS "bloat" which is a factor (but less that it used to be in many cases due to the wide-spread use of broadband connections). Whenever I can I will rebind to the original data-source; appropriate SQL-queries are *fast*. (There is no problem *changing* the binding source depending on current operation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataTable` is quite a large object - storing it in `ViewState` will bloat it and add to the download times of each request it is present on. In this respect not good for performance.

In terms of security - `ViewState` can be deciphered on the client side, so the `DataTable` is not secure.

What you need to do depends on what you are trying to achieve (which you have not indicated at all in your question).

You may want to store it server side in the `Cache` or `Session` objects, re-fetch it from the data store. It depends on the requirements.

Comment: good point Oded may be if you can offer what OP should be doing

Comment: @SurjitSamra - Without knowing what he is doing with the DataTable, not really.

Comment: @Oded Check the Modified Question Sir.

Comment: I gave this a -1 because it makes the ViewState sound insecure. Enter in a MAC and encryption and *viola*, argument negated. Also the *size* of a DataTable ultimately depends on the amount of data it contains (ignoring the encoding quality of the default serialization implementation) ..

Answer (score 2):

No it is not good practices to do it, storing a datatable in the viewstate will make your page grow big in size, thus slow both for the users and for your server to process.

If you need to keep the datatable around, you can add it to a Cache or just requery it every time

Comment: -1. I do it all the time *and it works well*. However, this doesn't mean "load a 10MB dataset viewstate". I gave the -1 because this is a hammer answer and does not address the validity (or lack thereof) of the approach. The ViewState (for "reasonably sized data") is a perfectly acceptable location to store per-user/page data, **including data in a DataTable**. However, it is generally *best* to re-bind from the source (e.g. use the DT only when the user is doing a temporal modification of the dataset).

Comment: (Also it should be noted that the *default* DataTable serialization is less than ideal ..)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the viewstate should be kept small. Can't you store your datatable in a cache or in session(not so good).
Saying that it won't be secure depend if your viewstate is encrypted or not.

Comment: +1 (where I -1'ed the other two answers) because it gives some nice rules *without* adding misleading/incorrect information ..